# No sound from earbuds(3.5mm jack), internal speakers produce sound.(19.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, kde, alsa, headphones

I apologize for the limited scope of the details of my problem. I have used alsamixer to make sure that my earbuds are not muted. Upon insertion, plasma indicator automatically switches volume controller to earbuds and mutes internal speakers. My output tests include Plasma Audio Volume control settings, VLC(which does not appear to recognize my earbuds in device selection), and youtube.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling plasma-desktop, kubuntu-desktop.